# Adding an icon to a custom action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How do I set an icon inside a custom action bar? Preferably I would like the icon to show only in the overflow. Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.myActionBar);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to set up your custom action bar

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.myActionBar, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Then you add your icons in like you do here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html